# Converting string to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a database table named "events" with a column named "date." Entries under that in the format of "Sunday, August 05, 2012". I show it using events.date. How would I convert that string to a date with integers (like 8/5/12), and show it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, for exact result, i.e. "8/5/12", you should try this:

```
Date.parse("Sunday, August 05, 2012").strftime("%1m/%1d/%y")
```

Answer (score 1):

you would use rails i18n features for this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Date.parse("Sunday, August 05, 2012").strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```